# Open dynamic Link from AJAX return using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to convert my queries from PHP to Ajax.

I am currently using this to return song id results from PHP.

```
<a href="javascript:songinfo(<?php echo $currentSong->ID; ?>)" title="Lyrics and song info"></a><?php echo $currentSong->title; ?>
```

using this i get something like this

http://chennaichristianradio.com/PHP/web/songinfo.php?songID=5506

How do I get the same results from Ajax, and get a returned address that is the same as above? the song id at the end is the info that is pulled from my database. This will be used for someone to click on this link to open a new page showing the contents of song id 5506.

You can see what i am attempting to do using using my current PHP here. Just clike on one of the "song info" buttons.

http://chennaichristianradio.com/PHP/web/history.php

I attempted the following using AJAX without success. Don't laugh to loudly over my code as I am just learning AJAX and PHP.

Script

```
document.getElementById('ID').innerHTML =  aj_ID "<a href="songinfo.php?songID=+ aj_results[7] + >"
```

and in HTML

```
<a href="javascript:songinfo(<div id="id"></div>)" title="Lyrics and song info"><img src="../../images/info.png" alt="Track information" width="70" height="22" border="none" title="Song Info and Lyrics" /></a>
```

Thank you for your help

Edited:
Here is my ajax Script

```
<?php
//Sam Broadcaster - AJAX Module - Send Artist/Title/Duration and Seconds remaining to getXMLHTTPRequest
//Written, cobbled together by wilksy101. This code contain code sourced from the support forums and stuff written myself


    // Change to your database user name
    $username="************"; 


    //Change to your database password
    $password="************"; 


    // Change to your database name
    $database="************"; 

    // Connect to the database  
    mysql_connect('ccronline.dyndns.info',$username,$password);

    // Handle an error
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

        // Build Sql that returns the data needed - change this as required.    
        $sql = "SELECT songlist.*, historylist.listeners as listeners, historylist.requestID as requestID, historylist.date_played as starttime FROM historylist,songlist WHERE (historylist.songID = songlist.ID) AND (songlist.songtype='S' OR songlist.songtype='C' OR songlist.songtype='N') ORDER BY historylist.date_played DESC LIMIT 1";


        // Store results in result object
        $result = mysql_query($sql);


         //store values in vars for calculation for array creation
        $curPlay = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM historylist ORDER BY date_played DESC LIMIT 1");
        $curPlayRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($curPlay);
        if (!$curPlay) { echo( mysql_error()); }
        $dt_duration = mysql_result($result,$i,'duration');
        $title= mysql_result($result,$i,'title');
        $artist= mysql_result($result,$i,'artist');
        $album= mysql_result($result,$i,'album');
        $picture= rawurlencode(mysql_result($result,$i,'picture'));
        $lyrics= mysql_result($result,$i,'lyrics');
        $ID= mysql_result($result,$i,'ID');
        $curtime = time();
        $timeleft = $starttime+round($dt_duration/1000)-$curtime;
        $secsRemain = (round($dt_duration / 1000)-($curtime-$starttime));

        //build array to return via getXMLHTTPRequest object - you can include more vars but remeber to handle them
        //correcty in the useHttpResponse function      
        $Aj_array = $dt_duration . '|' . $secsRemain . '|' . $title . '|' . $artist .'|' . $album .'|' . $picture .'|' . $lyrics .'|' . $ID;

        //we are using the text response object  - which i think is easier for small data return
        //just echo the array                 - not so much AJAX rather AJA ??
        echo $Aj_array

?>
```

Comment: wait ajax is not a php script it's a way to interact with a server side script via javascript (jquery is easier to go) performing post-load and asynchronous calls. please refer to this link http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp for general understanding and to this other link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for easy use via jQuery

Comment: The script you provided is PHP, not AJAX. Where's your `songinfo` function?

Comment: @Onheiron Please **do not** refer anyone to w3schools.  Please read [w3Fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com).

Answer (score 0):

so you are basically trying to get the content that you are currently displaying in the popup window at http://chennaichristianradio.com/PHP/web/history.php to appear within the same page using AJAX?

I think the main problem you have here is that you haven't established a relationship between the song and its listing html elements.

Try changing all of your "fill" divs  to have an id that includes the song number EG: "fill5669" you can then use this to determine where in the page to load the content from your ajax call like in this example:

```
function songInfo(songID){
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{// support OLD crusty versions of IE.
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                document.getElementById('fill'+songID).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://chennaichristianradio.com/PHP/web/songinfo.php?songID="+songID,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hello underscorePez. I am not sure i understand you when you say fill. These pages are created dynamically. My PHP currently querries the MySQL db and asks what is playing and returns a ID, along with the artist title and more. I want AXAX to do the same. I have been able to get it to pull the data, but the songinfo.php page along with the song id is my last piece of the puzzle. You can see the above script in action by going to http://bangalorechristianradio.com/ . This page shows a box at the top that has the AJAX return, and below there is a player that is getting its data from PHP.

Comment: in the page at http://chennaichristianradio.com/PHP/web/history.php you have multiple HTML elements with the same HTML id. Every one of these divs has an id of "fill". This is invalid xHTML and prevents you easily addressing your element in javascript. The box on your other page is just an iframe, if you replaced the iframe with <div id="mybox"> and changed the document.getElementById('fill'+songID) in my code to document.getElementById('mybox') then I think you'd have what you want.